# Drupal: hiding the view to display the results?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-5

i m newbie to drupal 
i have a view which displays the list of cars , i have 2 filters which are exposed make users to search for the car model and price.

it works fine, now i want this view to be home page, by default views gives list of all the nodes.
i dont want that, the results should display after users presses apply button

can any one help me to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Go to /admin/settings/site-information and enter the path to your view in the "Default front page" field.

PS. your site cannot be Drupal 5 and Drupal 6 at the same time. Please tag your questions correctly.

Comment: sorry for my bad english...
i know how to set the view as home page...
but my problem is to hide the nodes... u may have noticed that views displays all the contents by default..
now i don want my users to see all the results till they press apply button....

hope i m clear this time ...